# Regression analysis for multiple related outcomes

Tags: regression, logistic

This is my first post in CrossValidated :)

I have the dependent variables:
1. Coughing when being fed liquid (Yes/No)
2. Coughing when being fed solid (Yes/No)
and an independent variable:
1. Age group

I am thinking of using logistic regression method to answer the question "Is coughing related to age?". However, I am not sure how to accommodate both dependent variables in the model. I note the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26197/using-multinomial-logistic-regression-for-multiple-related-outcomes) about multiple related outcome analysis but would like ask for your advice if it's relevant to my analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have two dependent variables.  Do you have both (liquid/solid) observations for the same individuals, or are the people being fed liquids and solids from separate sets?

Comment: It's from the same individual. I have attempted to use both responses as separate incidence of the outcome (coughing) and run a logistic regression analysis adjusted for outcomes being sampled within group (individual) but not sure if it's the right way to go.

Comment: See the following https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564781/fitting-a-bivariate-logit-model-in-r-using-binom2-or-and-model-diagnostics, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411236/binary-logistic-regression-with-two-dependent-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594268/multivariate-logistic-regression-r