# Binary logistic regression with two dependent variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binary-data, multivariate-regression

I have a continuous independent variable, X, and two binary dependent variables, Y and Z. I'm trying to run a binary logistic regression that models the correlation between Y and Z. X = age, while Y and Z are two pass/fail tasks. I want to determine the probability of an individual passing a given task at a given age, but I also want to test whether individuals who pass one task tend to also pass the other.

How should I go about doing this? I've tried the following in R:

```
  glm(cbind(Z,Y)~X, family="binomial", data= my_data)
```

This gives me a coefficient of -0.02335 for X. However, when I reverse the order of (Z,Y) in the formula above, the X coefficient becomes positive. Why is that?

Does anyone know how to run a binary logistic regression in R with correlated dependent variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it wrong, there are [three possible input formats for logistic regression](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.0/topics/family) in R

> 1. As a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the
>      first level (and hence usually of having the second level).
> 2. As a
>      numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the
>      proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given
>      by the weights).
> 3. **As a two-column integer matrix: the first column
>      gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures.**

Logistic regression is an univariate model, if you have two target variables, then you need to use a different model (there are a number of choices, including the bivariate logistic regression model given by [Palmgren (1989), "Regression Models for Bivariate Binary Responses", *UW Biostatistics Working Paper Series*, 101](https://biostats.bepress.com/uwbiostat/paper101), and implemented by [`binom2.or`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/0.8-3/topics/binom2.or) in the [VGAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) package).

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I see that Zelig has a package for bivariate logistic regression too: http://docs.zeligproject.org/articles/zeligchoice_blogit.html. I'll try both packages, and see how I go.