# When to use offset in binomial glm

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution, offset

I am trying to model the number of successes in data where the number of trials is not fixed. I am trying to fit a binomial generalised mixed effects model, with the number of trials as an 'offset' variable, like so:

```r
        glmer(cbind(number of successes, number of failures) ~ 
         offset(number of trials) + other fixed and random 
         effects, data = data, family = binomial())
```

Is this the correct way to use offset?

Comment: Why not a Poisson with an offset?

Answer (score 1):

The information on the number of trials is already there. The number of trials = number of successes + number of failures. You [can provide](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411236/binary-logistic-regression-with-two-dependent-variables/411241#411241) inputs for logistic regression as a column of zeroes and ones, probabilities, or two columns for successes and failures. In neither of the cases, there is a reason to provide the number of trials as a separate variable.

Comment: That's helpful clarification, thanks.